# Very Slow on Azure VHD Initialization (Lucene.Net)

Tags: azure, lucene.net, vhd

I build a Lucene.Net index (around 250M, still growing) on VHD in Windows Azure.
I have 10G local cache for the VHD

However, the Initialization is very slow, which cause almost all requests involve fulltext search failed in first 1-2 minutes when the Azure instance newly restarted.

My question:

1. is there anyway to preload VHD to local cache?
2. is there anyway to force Lucene.Net gives results(even null) rather than fail with exceptions.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a Windows Azure Web/Worker Role and you are using a VHD mounted in the role to create Lucene.net index? Based on your answer I can provide much better approach.

Comment: I use 1 role to mount the VHD, then share to network. Other roles in same deployment use the shared drive. The Lucene Index is on VHD, after mount, will be on Z:

Answer (score 0):

1. i don't know about Lucene.Net but, you cloud just read the most importand files(just get the data but dont do anything with it) this will "warm" the cache 
   then report the role as ready
2. you could just catch and do something with it (watch out doug)

try this(is in vb):

```
function getData()
  try{
    return some.lucene.code
  }catch e as exception' have some smarter tings here this is dangerous
    trace.TraceError("Lucene trew:"+e.ToString)
    return Nothing
  }
End Function
```